# Why copy function arguments into local variables?

Tags: c, string.h

What is the reason for [strlcpy.c](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/strlcpy.c?rev=1.11;content-type=text/plain) to copy the arguments into local variables:

```
size_t
strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t siz)
{
    char *d = dst;
    const char *s = src;
    size_t n = siz;

    /* Copy as many bytes as will fit */
    if (n != 0) {
        while (--n != 0) {
            if ((*d++ = *s++) == '\0')
                break;
        }
    }

    /* Not enough room in dst, add NUL and traverse rest of src */
    if (n == 0) {
        if (siz != 0)
            *d = '\0';      /* NUL-terminate dst */
        while (*s++)
            ;
    }

    return(s - src - 1);    /* count does not include NUL */
}
```

**Update**

I added the body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One very common reason is that the variables are modified in the function, and then used in an expression together with the arguments.

For example, the function might modify the variable `n`, and later do e.g. `return siz - n;`.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil Because that pointer may be modified as well. Think `while (...) { *d++ = *s++; }`

Answer (score 1):

Actually in the rest of the code siz and src are needed to calculate some stuff:

```
/* Not enough room in dst, add NUL and traverse rest of src */
if (n == 0) {
    if (siz != 0)
        *d = '\0';      /* NUL-terminate dst */
    while (*s++)
        ;
}

return(s - src - 1);    /* count does not include NUL */
```

But I can't see why dst is copied locally. Maybe just for symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

At least for the `src` argument, it's used to calculate the length to return. The final line of that function shows that:

```
return(s - src - 1);
```

In terms of the `dst` argument, it's not actually needed but it *may* have been done for consistency. It probably doesn't matter because a decent optimising compiler will probably not be affected by this seemingly extra variable.

Comment: The "unnecessary" scanning isn't unnecessary. The `strl*` functions were very carefully designed. [You can read the paper](http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix99/full_papers/millert/millert.pdf). The relevant part is: "a return value with the same semantics as snprintf()’s was a better choice since it gives the
programmer the most ﬂexibility with respect to truncation detection and recovery."

Comment: @Art, that's a good point, I didn't realise at first it was specified to return the length of the _source_ rather than the number of characters copied. Removed my erroneous assumption.

Answer (score 1):

For `dst` and `d`, I think, just for symmetry. For the other variables they are used in "code" both with their initial and updated values.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t
strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t siz)
{                     ^-------------------------->constant so must not be modified. that's why a temp variable is needed for modification.     
    char *d = dst;     <-- useless may be.
    const char *s = src;
    size_t n = siz;      

    /* Copy as many bytes as will fit */
    if (n != 0) {        
        while (--n != 0) {
            if ((*d++ = *s++) == '\0')
                break;
        }
    }

    /* Not enough room in dst, add NUL and traverse rest of src */
    if (n == 0) {                    <-- new n arg.
        if (siz != 0)              <---  original siz arg
            *d = '\0';      /* NUL-terminate dst */
        while (*s++)
            ;
    }

    return(s - src - 1);    /* count does not include NUL */  <-- using the original and modified values of s and src together.
}
```

Comment: hey pls tell about the useless ?

Answer (score 0):

*d and *s pointed to original pointer address dst and src, but later it has been increased to copy single byte. So, it lost original pointer address, but arguments dst and src pointer still keep the original pointer address.